# How do they draw this in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do they draw this in Latex ?

[image]

Comment: Search here for trees.

Comment: Package `tikz-cd` should do it very simply.

Comment: Although you already have an answer, your question is still a just-do-it-for-me question, and we overall dislike those questions. Next time make sure that you will add an MWE showing what you've tried. We prefer fixing to creating.

Comment: @JouleV I don't know this. But the user was removed?

Comment: @Sebastiano I think he deleled his account after seeing my comment. Is my comment attacking him?

Comment: @JouleV My simple answer is: no!

Comment: @Sebastiano Well, I don't know why but I'm now a bit uncomfortable when reading just-do-it-for-me questions. Maybe I'm becoming allergic to such questions after a series of 7 questions I saw yesterday.

Comment: @JouleV Look down. Four answers. You might have missed something, this community is right now quite comfortable with *Just-do-it-for-me*. An answer makes someone happy in providing them with an answes ... *and* it gives some free (real-world) worthless reputation.

Comment: @Johannes_B Indeed, and that is what we have in [this meta question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/explicitly-indicate-the-reasons-why-answering-a-just-do-it-for-me-question). Well, I do have free-time but I am not a reputation seeker.

Comment: @JouleV Just opted for https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8116/reasons-for-closing-questions-too-little-effort

Comment: @JouleV When I joined more than two years ago, however, for my first question, I didn't even know where to start. Yet they helped me. I understand your frustration but from my point of view if it is the first time that a user who asks a question Just-do-it-for-me in my opinion there is nothing wrong. If then the same user persists in the Just-do-it-for-me questions then the speech changes totally. I think you should be patient and not angry.

Comment: @Sebastiano Oh yes, I am not angry, I am just a bit uncomfortable. I have my own rule! If user182626 has been here for a while, I will vote to close the question, but because he is a new user, I don't do it. And I am sad that this question got closed. Because he is new here, I just suggest him to add an MWE to his _next_ questions.

Answer (score 5):

Pure tikz?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1) {1}; 
\node (2) [below left=of 1] {2};
\node (3) [below right=of 2] {3};
\node (4) [below right=of 1] {4};
\draw (1)--(2) (1)--(4) (2)--(3) (3)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A shorter version with a `\foreach` loop: [PS: similar to @marmot's answer below]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \node (\i) at (90*\i:1cm) {\i};
\draw (1)--(2) (1)--(4) (2)--(3) (3)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `tikz-cd`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep= .7cm, column sep=.5cm]
& 1 \arrow[ld, no head] &\\
2 \arrow[rd, no head] && 4 \arrow[lu, no head] \\
& 3 \arrow[ru, no head] &                      
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Loops can help avoid repetition and polar coordinates help to make things more symmetric.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X in {1,...,4} {\node (\X) at (\X*90:1) {\X};} 
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially 4)] in {1,...,4} 
{\draw (\LastX) -- (\X);} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A short code with `pstricks` and `multido`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node, multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1cm, colsep=1.25cm]
 & 1 \\ 2 & & 4 \\ & 3
\end{psmatrix}
\multido{\ir=1+2}{2}{\multido{\ic=1+2}{2}{\ncline[nodesep=4pt, linewidth=0.5pt]{\ir,2}{2,\ic}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]